# how to read contents from PUT request and grab the file contents in variable php

Tags: php, fopen, put

below is the code which i want to modify

```
 $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
        $temp = tmpfile();
        $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
        fclose($input);

        if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){            
            return false;
        }

        $target = fopen($path, "w");        
        fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
        fclose($target);
```

I want to save the contents into the memory and transfer it accross to other server without saving it on apache server.

when i try to output the contents i only see resource id# 5. Any suggestion, comments are highly apprecited . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have opens file handles, which in themselves are not *the content*. To get the content into a variable, just read it like any other file:

```
$put = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the contents of the stream:

```
rewind($temp); // rewind the stream to the beginning
$contents = stream_get_contents($temp);
var_dump($contents);
```

Or, use `file_get_contents` as @deceze mentions.

---

**UPDATE**

I noticed you're also opening a temp file on disk. You might want to consider simplifying your code like so:

```
$put = stream_get_contents(STDIN); // STDIN is an open handle to php://input
if ($put) {
  $target = fopen('/storage/put.txt', "w");        
  fwrite($target, $put);
  fclose($target);
}
```